# How to stream remote audio in iOS 13? (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, avplayer, swiftui, ios13, swift5

This code using `AVPlayer` works only on **Playground**

```
import AVFoundation

    var player = AVPlayer()
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3")!)
      player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
      player.play()
```

When I tried to run it on my SwiftUI App on my physical device, using this code:

```
 Button(action:{

              var player = AVPlayer()
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3")!)
                  player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
                  player.play()

            print("Works")

               },label:{

                   Image("play")
          })
```

It prints **Works** to the console. However, it does not play any sound on the device.

Would appreciate any help, can't find anything yet here.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SwiftUI, Views are value types. They are only data that *describe* the things on screen. They can be created or destroyed or copied at any time. AVPlayer is a reference to a specific player object. You're assuming here that it will continue to exist, and there will only be one of them. That's not something that a SwiftUI View provides.

You need to move your AVPlayer outside of the View (into Model objects), and just bind UI actions to it.