# Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

Can someone tell me why on line 9  I get the error Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred

```
struct PlayerControlsView : View {
  @State var playerPaused = true
  @State var seekPos = 0.0
  let player: AVPlayer
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Button(action: {
        self.playerPaused.toggle()
        if self.playerPaused {
          self.player.pause()
        }
        else {
          self.player.play()
        }
      }) {
        Image(systemName: playerPaused ? "play" : "pause")
          .padding(.leading, CGFloat(20))
          .padding(.trailing, CGFloat(20))
      }
      Slider(value: $seekPos, from: 0, through: 1, onEditingChanged: { _ in
        guard let item = self.player.currentItem else {
          return
        }

        let targetTime = self.seekPos * item.duration.seconds
        self.player.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: targetTime, preferredTimescale: 600))
      })
        .padding(.trailing, CGFloat(20))
    }
  }
}
```

And of course how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Slider` init is incorrect. There is no version that has `from:` and `through:`. `in: [0...1]` is the default, though, so you don't need it anyway.

```
  Slider(value: $seekPos, onEditingChanged: { _ in
```

SwiftUI error messages are generally useless. The way you find the error is to keep commenting out things until it compiles, and then add them back in.

However, what you're doing here isn't going to work. You can't put a `AVPlayer` inside a `View`. A `View` is a struct, and they get created, copied, and destroyed all the time. See [How to stream remote audio in iOS 13? (SwiftUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792160/how-to-stream-remote-audio-in-ios-13-swiftui).

Comment: Ok. That fixed that, but now im getting the error Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable on self.player.pause()

Comment: Correct; putting the player inside the struct is going to fail in lots of ways. You cannot put an AVPlayer inside a View. You need a model class that you bind to the View as a BindableObject. (Or as a Singleton, or any other way you want to access it, but you can't put an AVPlayer inside a View.)

Comment: So, I was following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@chris.mash/avplayer-swiftui-part-2-player-controls-c28b721e7e27 --- but it's too buggy. Can you show me a way of implementing a video with a pause and play? a seek bar would be nice too.